# Debug go vendor modules with VS Code?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have been trying to debug a dependency from vendor-folder with VS Code.

When starting a debugger binary is built using vendor/ files but VS Code does not allow to set break points to files under vendor/

Has anyone had success using debugger in vendor/?

Comment: what happens if you set a break point in the called functions in your code, and then you step inside ?

Comment: debugger goes to vendor/ files. Found the reason, I tried to set breakpoint to a function that was never called.